# Ho do i separate a partition from existing partion

Tags: partitioning

I have installed ubuntu in my system, I did not create any partition, Now i want to separate a partition from existing drive.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the 'Gparted' software for that. But that does not come with ubuntu 16.04.1. so you have to get it from the software center.

Or type in the terminal as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

then in Gparted, right click the partition you want to shrink or reduce the size for and select '**unmount**' it the partition is other than 'ext4' type. Then right click again and select '**Resize/Move**'.

After you have resized the partition. click '**Apply all operations**' from the tool-bar at the top(green tick) or from the '**Edit**' menu

Then right click on the partition line that reads '**unallocated**' or '**free space**' and select '**new**'.

Now specify the filesystem type, size and a name(label) and press '**Add**'
and then once again select '**Apply all operations**'.

Repeat the process as necessary.